# dnu pack is nesting library folders in nupkg

Tags: nuget, dnu

I have an interesting issue that I'm trying to resolve. The resulting nuget library from running a `dnu pack --out <path>` command is invalid. The folder structure inside of it is lib\dnx46\dnx46\ when it should be lib\dnx46\. There is that extra dnx46 folder. When I run `dnu pack` without the `--out <path>` it works fine as well as building the project with "produce outputs on build" checked. Has any body else seen this problem and know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a bug. It was due to the path using forward slashes `/` and not backslashes `\`. When I changed my output path to use `\` it started working again.

Here is a link to the github issue. https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/253